# Grouping values of a column into categories in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have data in R that I want to compare by using the values in the first column. The category name is already included in the first column before the actual values of that category. The issue is that, as it stands, the category name is treated as a value. I want to organize this data into "A" and "B" categories (and A and B not considered as values) and then perform comparisons between 'Team A' and 'Team B'. How do I do that?

| Organization | Team A | Team B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 23 |
| Cat | 55 | 41 |
| Dog | 22 | 33 |
| Pig | 52 | 85 |
| B | 12 | 12 |
| Lion | 32 | 44 |
| Tiger | 43 | 55 |
| Elephant | 85 | 69 |

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output for this sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have a list of categories, we can make a column that copies those over from Organization when they match, and fill those values down over the NAs.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 |>
  mutate(category = if_else(Organization %in% c("A", "B"), Organization, NA)) |>
  fill(category)
```

Result

```
  Organization Team.A Team.B category
1            A     10     23        A
2          Cat     55     41        A
3          Dog     22     33        A
4          Pig     52     85        A
5            B     12     12        B
6         Lion     32     44        B
7        Tiger     43     55        B
8     Elephant     85     69        B
```

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      Organization = c("A","Cat","Dog","Pig","B",
                       "Lion","Tiger","Elephant"),
            Team.A = c(10L, 55L, 22L, 52L, 12L, 32L, 43L, 85L),
            Team.B = c(23L, 41L, 33L, 85L, 12L, 44L, 55L, 69L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This groups/categorizes the data into "A" and "B" based on finding a single character in *Organization*.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(nchar(Organization) == 1)) %>% 
  mutate(grp = first(Organization))
# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   grp [2]
  Organization `Team A` `Team B` grp  
  <chr>           <int>    <int> <chr>
1 A                  10       23 A    
2 Cat                55       41 A    
3 Dog                22       33 A    
4 Pig                52       85 A    
5 B                  12       12 B    
6 Lion               32       44 B    
7 Tiger              43       55 B    
8 Elephant           85       69 B
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Organization = c("A", "Cat", "Dog", "Pig", "B", 
"Lion", "Tiger", "Elephant"), `Team A` = c(10L, 55L, 22L, 52L, 
12L, 32L, 43L, 85L), `Team B` = c(23L, 41L, 33L, 85L, 12L, 44L, 
55L, 69L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```